# Visualforce - Display Controller Extension Member Variable Data

Tags: visualforce, javascript

My VF Page :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Expense__c" extensions="ExpenseController"  sidebar="false" showHeader="true" showChat="false" recordSetVar="exp" >
<script src="../../soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<apex:form >

<apex:inlineEditSupport />

<apex:pageBlock title="List of Expenses">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!exp}" var="item" >
<apex:column value="{!item.Date__c}"/>

<apex:column value="{!item.Type__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!item.Amount__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!item.Comments__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton1" onclick="alert('Saving the changes...')"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Total" id="theButton2" onclick="alert('Displaying the total...')"/>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My Controller Extension Class :

```
public with sharing class ExpenseController
{

private ApexPages.StandardSetController sc;
public Integer SumOfAllExpenses = 0;

public ExpenseController(ApexPages.StandardSetController sc)
{
this.sc = sc;
displayTotal();
}


public void displayTotal()
{

List<AggregateResult> i = [SELECT SUM(Amount__c) FROM Expense__c];
SumOfAllExpenses = Integer.valueOf(i[0].get('expr0'));
}

public PageReference save()
{

sc.save();
PageReference p = new PageReference('/apex/addExpenses');
return p;

}


}
```

My requirement :

Display data of the member variable (SumOfAllExpenses) from ExpenseController class in the pop up of

```
<apex:commandButton value="Total" id="theButton2" onclick="alert('Displaying the total...')"/>
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the value available by having a getter in the controller. One common pattern to use is this get using lazy initialization (remove the displayTotal method);

```
public Integer SumOfAllExpenses {
    get {
        if (SumOfAllExpenses == null) {
            List<AggregateResult> i = [SELECT SUM(Amount__c) FROM Expense__c];
            SumOfAllExpenses = Integer.valueOf(i[0].get('expr0'));
        }
        return SumOfAllExpenses;
    }
    private set;
}
```

The value is then be made part of the JavaScript string when the Visualforce generates the HTML page:

```
onclick="alert('Sum of all expenses is {!SumOfAllExpenses}')"
```